# Installing Nvidia-396 on Ubuntu Mate laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ubuntu-mate, external-monitor

So, I have a problem with using the Nvidia-396 driver in Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

I have a brand new HP Pavilion Power 15-CB084NO laptop with a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 graphics card, and I'm trying to use an external monitor connected via HDMI. However, Ubuntu Mate doesn't detect any signal from the monitor when I'm in "Monitor Preferences" and pressing "Detect Monitors." (Windows 10 can detect the monitor on the same laptop, so it's not a hardware problem.)

I have installed nvidia-driver-396, and in "Software & Updates / Additional Drivers," it appears that it's working (see screenshot below):

[Screenshot Software and Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXhlZ.png)

But for some reason, it appears that it's not working anyway, and that this is the reason why I can't get a signal on the external monitor.

When I type "cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log" in terminal, a part of the reply is:

```
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Does anybody know how to fix this in Mate?